# Change the root node in a binary tree

Tags: rust, binary-tree

I wrote a binary tree of i32. I want to change its root node to left node. But always failed.  How to do it?

```rust
fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self.root.as_mut() {
            Some(root) => match root.left {
                Some(left) => {
                    self.root = Some(left); // this line always failed
                    return Ok(());
                }
                None => {
                    return Err(Error::NotFound);
                }
            },
            None => {
                return Err(Error::EmptyTree);
            }
        }
    }
```

`self.root = Some(left)` I think it is easy to do this, but always failed.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `root.left.0` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> src/main.rs:120:33
    |
120 |             Some(root) => match root.left {
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&root.left`
121 |                 Some(left) => {
    |                      ----
    |                      |
    |                      data moved here
    |                      move occurs because `left` has type `Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ecc5a515cc623e5707405decfc390914)

Comment: Please provide the attempts that you have done, and the errors you have encountered that you don't understand, rather than your whole code, most of which is not related to your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have changed.

Comment: As always, I'd like to mention that building data structures is not a good way to learn Rust, because it's pretty hard. But if you must, you might want to have a look at [Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::mem::take`, which allows taking things out of a mutable reference to them (replacing the pointed value with the default value of that type). That is, your function `left` can be rewritten:

```rust
use std::mem::take;

fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let root = self.root.as_mut().ok_or(Error::EmptyTree)?;
    let left = take(&mut root.left).ok_or(Error::NotFound)?;
    *root = left;
    Ok(())
}
```

---

**Edit**: turns out there is a method that does exactly that. I'll leave my first snippet so that you understand what happens, but the following is probably more suitable in real code.

```rust
fn left(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let root = self.root.as_mut().ok_or(Error::EmptyTree)?;
    let left = root.left.take().ok_or(Error::NotFound)?;
    *root = left;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Using `Option::take` might be a tad more elegant in this case. But `mem::take` is good for an SO answer, nicely generic.

Comment: @Caesar ah, nice one! I didn't know that method existed.